# solution to word puzzle in quarantine circular

Tags: quarantine-circular

Recently played most of the way through quarantine circular and thoroughly enjoyed the experience right up until I came up against a word puzzle I just can't figure out.

It's the puzzle for:

> Zima's phage keyword

Does anyone know the answer? 
I've searched for it but there aren't many FAQs or walkthroughs available yet for this game.

Puzzle text copied below - first:

> My first is in cake but not in casserole (K?).

Second:

> My second, third and fourth are human but forgiveness is divine (A,I,O,E) then (RR,WE,IO,VE).

Third:

> My last is a question. (S,EY,Y or T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me far longer than it should have but ive figured out the answer.

The answer is:

> K, E, RR, Y. K in cake not casserole, err is to be human, and y as in "why", spelling the name Kerry.